# How to get the SSL certificate of a server running a web service from the client app? - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, x509certificate

I have a client program written in .NET 2.0, that connects to the web service.
I used Visual Studio to generate a class derived from SoapHttpClientProtocol,
every method was generated just fine, everything is working.

But - the web service is running only through HTTPS, so I was just wondering, how could I get an X509Certificate instance of the server's certificate.

I know the Framework does the validation of the server's certificate transparently, so I dont need to care of the certificate validation in my code, but I what if I needed to read the certificate's serial number?

The SoapHttpClientProtocol base class seems to have only members/methods for client certificates.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You hook into the [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx). Your callback will be invoked with the server's [`X509Certificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx) and you can check anything you like on it, like the [`Issuer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.issuer%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [`SerialNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getserialnumberstring%28VS.80%29.aspx).